# How can I custom limit the extent of an ArcGIS basemap?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am writing web application based on ArcGIS API for javascript. So far I managed to create empty map using [this tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-mapview/index.html) and write some code which visualizes some data.

The basemaps which ArcGIS offer are quite nice and I would like to use them, but they represent whole world and what I need is basemap of just a single country. What's the best/easiest way to do it? I tried using ArcGIS Online to edit basemap but the don't offer good options for cutting single country.

I found some links out there but they aren't solving my problem (or my knowledge is to small to understand them), for example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/basemap-custom/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you like the look and feel of the Esri basemaps, you don't want to make your own. That's certainly [technically possible](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-tiles.htm), but requires a greater command of ArcMap and publishing services -- and isn't what you're really looking for. And basemap tiles shouldn't be edited, even ones you publish yourself, since the difficulty of doing that well is just not worth the effort.

Instead, you can **restrict the JavaScript map to prevent panning outside your area of interest**. Whenever the user moves to an extent that exceeds allowed values, the code automatically resets the extent to the allowed limit, and they can't move outside it. (You can similarly restrict zoom levels so they won't even be able to zoom out further than the view of your area of interest.)

For code details, see existing answers on [Restricting base map on specific extent in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/66568/15768) (GIS.StackExchange)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try do it this way ;)